# animation loop in a separate thread, Native Client

Tags: multithreading, google-nativeclient

In Native Client, is it possible to set up animation loop in a separate thread? I was not able to find any examples that do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean OpenGL ES 2.0 based animations, then NO, you have to make all OpenGL calls from the main thread. But you can keep different threads for calculating framecounters or other calculations.

Only restriction is to make all OpenGL calls from main thread.

Comment: Thank you for tips. I found something similar for my needs. This app called xaos and it is ported to NaCl and currently fixed to work with help of pepper22.